# Spoof My IP Address in HTTP Request with PHP Script

Tags: php, sockets, curl, ip

I a trying to change my address with the help of CURLOPT_PROXY Header with the help of curl request ; but its not working. I just want to ask if its possible to **spoof my IP Address in a HTTP request** , if yes please tell me how to implement it.

Comment: In that case, how do you plan to get a response back, since the server will then send it to the spoofed address? (of course, just in case you care about that)

Comment: ... and given that HTTP is TCP based, I'm pretty sure that not getting a response to the initial syn packet isn't going to be that productive

Comment: Go through this link [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the same issue , for this you need the full 3-way SYN/ACK handshake  this link helped me in getting out of the problem [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/381393/can-the-ip-address-for-an-http-request-be-spoofed)